# How to save emails as MS Word or PDF files and save attachments in specific folders?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save selected emails in `docx` or `pdf` format and save each email and their
attachments within a folder named as the subject of each email.

The code below it works (borrowed from [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/save-messages-and-attachments-in-a-new-folder/)), but is saving the emails in html format. I'd changed this line to `docx` but doesn't work

```vb
objMsg.SaveAs strFolderpath & strName & ".docx", olHTML
```

Regarding the attachments, it saves the attachments but additionally is saving (as attachments) all images that appear in the email body.

Then, how to fix this code in order to save emails as `docx` or `pdf` and save only files that are actually attached?

```vb
Public Sub SaveMessagesAndAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    Dim sFileType As String
    Dim enviro As String
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
        
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oldName
        
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMsg = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    strName = StripIllegalChar(objMsg.Subject)
        
    strFolderpath = enviro & "\Documents\" & strName & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(strFolderpath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder (strFolderpath)
    End If
    
    objMsg.SaveAs strFolderpath & strName & ".htm", olHTML
    
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
            
        If lngCount > 0 Then
        
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        
        strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
        Debug.Print strFile
        strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
        objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    
        Next i
        End If
            
    ExitSub:
    
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
        Dim RegX            As Object    
        Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        
        RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
        RegX.IgnoreCase = True
        RegX.Global = True
        
        StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")
        
    ExitFunction:
        Set RegX = Nothing
        
End Function
```

Comment: [MailItem.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) "Also note that even though olDoc is a valid OlSaveAsType constant, messages in HTML format cannot be saved in Document format,..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save email body to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567406/save-email-body-to-word-document)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I changed to `objMsg.SaveAs strFolderpath & strName & ".doc", olDoc` and it works even is saving the file as `doc` not as `docx`.  Only try to wonder how to save only the attachement files and not the images in body. The images in body are already saved within `doc` file

Comment: [Distinguish visible and invisible attachments with Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310925/distinguish-visible-and-invisible-attachments-with-outlook-vba)